# Need bash script to find (if exists) a tar file, younger than 7 days old

Tags: file, bash, datetime, find, tar

Lots of people want to find files older than x days but in my case, I need to find a tar younger than 7 days old.

- Date format: date +%m-%d-%Y
- The file may not exist. If not, create tar from /location/.
- If file exists, append newer files to the tar from /location/.

If I can provide more details, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: I should state add that I want the oldest tar file returned from the initial search. ie. there will be more than one tar in the directory so, it is important to append to the oldest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prints the oldest tar file less than 604800 seconds old, if any:

```
find /location/ -name \*.tar -mtime -7 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -rt | head -1
```